# Pressing key with accent character makes it enter twice

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, 64-bit

I’ve got a very strange issue on my PC. Whenever I type an accent character, they appear as if I hit the key twice.

For example, when I type the following sequence:

```
`~TEST^"'
```

I get the following:

```
``~~TEST^^""''
```

Keyboard is configured as: `Dutch (Nederlands) - United States-International`

I’ve tried:

- Restarting the PC
- Changing the keyboard

I have no idea how to Google for this, or what this problem results from.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Please try this with - a new OS user - another OS (a live cd, recovery cd, etc) and write what you get.

Comment: This happens to me a lot in my computer at work (UK), I actually recently moved here and got myself a keyboard with my own language layout, language settings are set properly, but sometimes this exact same thing happens. A restart usually fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The United States-International keyboard layout provides a way to type special characters from various European languages on an standard US keyboard. For instance, to type **ë**, you would press <kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>. (US keyboards don't have a key for that character.) To type **"**, you have to press <kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>space</kbd>.

There is more information from Microsoft here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306560

You can install different keyboard layouts, and you can switch between them. The right one will depend on what sort of keyboard you have.